# Do I need a meningitis-C vaccination for Ireland?

Tags: health, ireland, vaccinations

I am due to fly from Delhi to Dublin, Ireland on the 14th of September 2019, with a layover in Istanbul.

Do I need Meningitis-C Vaccination?

Comment: What are you traveling to Ireland for? Just tourism?

Answer (score 2):

No.  It's not on the list of the [CDC](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/traveler/none/ireland) recommended vaccinations for Ireland, which include:

> Required: 
>   Measles       Infants (6 through 11 months old): 1 dose of
>   measles-mumps-rubella (MMR) vaccine before travel. This dose does not
>   count as the first dose in the routine childhood vaccination series.
>       People 12 months old or older, with no evidence of immunity or no written documentation of any doses: 2 doses of MMR vaccine before
>   travel. The 2 doses must be given 28 days apart.
>       People 12 months old or older who have written documentation of 1 dose and no other evidence of immunity: 1 additional dose before
>   travel, at least 28 days after the previous dose.
>
> Routine:
>
> Make sure you are up-to-date on routine vaccines before every trip.
>   These vaccines include measles-mumps-rubella (MMR) vaccine,
>   diphtheria-tetanus-pertussis vaccine, varicella (chickenpox) vaccine,
>   polio vaccine, and your yearly flu shot.

And others may require Hep A, Hep B and Rabies. See the link for more information.

Comment: It's not bad advice in general but Ireland is famously rabies free and polio isn't really an issue either but it doesn't hurt.